# Show number of submissions of a GravityForm by user

Tags: wordpress

I'm working to implement submission limits by user role within my WordPress app. I have it working, but before I roll it to production I'd like to also show the user how many more submissions they have left in that month.

I tried implementing the [Display Number of Entries Left shortcode](https://gravitywiz.com/shortcode-display-number-of-entries-left/), but this doesn't work on a per-user level and doesn't show anything when the form itself does not have an overall limit number.

Any help?

Comment: Please elaborate what exactly your problem is.

Comment: Hi Eriawan, looking for resources that might help me out.

Problem - I want to show the number of entries left by user on a specific form.
Problem 2 - the shortcode way I linked to doesn't work.

Comment: Alright, so here's what I have done: 1) Updated the snippet I'm using (https://gravitywiz.com/better-limit-submission-per-time-period-by-user-or-ip), 2) added in the add_action for get_current_user, 3) fixed get_current_user in the snippet to user $current_user instead of $user based off best practices. Now I get a "Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user() in" error. Is this possibly because I'm trying to load this from a plugin?